# Change Color Lookup texture during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, post-processing, urp

I'm trying to change the texture and contribution of the Color Lookup module of the post processing stack in URP.

Initially I tried simply modifying the value like this:

```
private void SetTheme(int index)
{
    if (index > 0 && ThemeColorLookups.Length > index)
    {
        if (_globalVolume.profile.TryGet(out ColorLookup cl))
        {
            cl.texture = new TextureParameter(ThemeColorLookups[index], true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (_globalVolume.profile.TryGet(out ColorLookup cl))
        {
            cl.texture = new TextureParameter(null, true);
        }
    }
}

private void SetThemeIntensity(int value)
{
    if (_globalVolume.profile.TryGet(out ColorLookup cl))
    {
        cl.contribution = new ClampedFloatParameter(value / 100f, 0, 1, true);
    }
}
```

This did change the values when inspecting the volume in the editor, however no changes where reflected in the game or scene view.

I also attempted completely swapping the Color Lookup instance with a new one, which more or less resulted in the same behavior as the previous approach.

```
private int _currentThemeIndex;
private float _currentThemeIntensity;

private void SetTheme(int index)
{
    if (index > 0 && ThemeColorLookups.Length > index)
    {
        _globalVolume.profile.Remove<ColorLookup>();

        var cl = _globalVolume.profile.Add<ColorLookup>();
        cl.contribution = new ClampedFloatParameter(_currentThemeIntensity, 0, 1, true);
        cl.texture = new TextureParameter(ThemeColorLookups[index], true);

        _currentThemeIndex = index;
    }
    else
    {
        _currentThemeIndex = 0;
        _globalVolume.profile.Remove<ColorLookup>();
    }
}

private void SetThemeIntensity(int value)
{
    _currentThemeIntensity = value / 100f;

    if (_currentThemeIndex == 0) { return; }

    _globalVolume.profile.Remove<ColorLookup>();

    var cl = _globalVolume.profile.Add<ColorLookup>();
    cl.contribution = new ClampedFloatParameter(value/100f, 0, 1, true);
    cl.texture = new TextureParameter(ThemeColorLookups[_currentThemeIndex], true);
}
```

Why are the changes not being reflected during time? If I manually modify the values during runtime the correct texture and contribution are displayed, however doing the "same" with code yields only an editor change.

It's worth noting that after this piece of code has been executed, which happens whenever you drag an UI slider, even if I attempt to modify the values manually through the editor, nothing happens (except obviously inspector update). So it basically gets bricked until I replay the scene. At which point I can again modify the values manually, however this is undesirable in my case. I would like to completely control the 2 exposed properties through code.

Unity version - 2021.2.19f1 using URP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by assigning a texture directly instead of a new textureparameter so instead of:

```
if (volume.profile.TryGet(out ColorLookup cl))
{
     cl.texture.value = new TextureParameter(texture, true);
}
```

Try this instead:

```
if (volume.profile.TryGet(out ColorLookup cl))
{
    cl.texture.value = texture;
}
```

The reason it doesn't work with assigning a new parameter is that the system doesn't respond to changes made to objects that aren't tied to an existing component, meaning any changes you make by creating a new instance will not be reflected in the scene.

Answer (score 2):

Although [Merijn Kersten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8944498/merijn-kersten)'s answer is working there is a better way to change a texture at runtime.

In the code you provided, you're trying to modify the `ColorLookup` component on the `_globalVolume` object, but modifying values on an object during runtime will not automatically update the object in the scene.

You can use the `SetDirty` method on the `_globalVolume` object after modifying its values. This will tell Unity to save the changes and update the object in the scene.

```
{
    if (index > 0 && ThemeColorLookups.Length > index)
    {
        if (_globalVolume.profile.TryGet(out ColorLookup cl))
        {
            cl.texture = new TextureParameter(ThemeColorLookups[index], true);
            _globalVolume.SetDirty();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (_globalVolume.profile.TryGet(out ColorLookup cl))
        {
            cl.texture = new TextureParameter(null, true);
            _globalVolume.SetDirty();
        }
    }
}

private void SetThemeIntensity(int value)
{
    if (_globalVolume.profile.TryGet(out ColorLookup cl))
    {
        cl.contribution = new ClampedFloatParameter(value / 100f, 0, 1, true);
        _globalVolume.SetDirty();
    }
}
```

[Merijn Kersten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8944498/merijn-kersten)'s solution works because he directly assigns a `Texture` object to the `texture.value` property, meaning he is modifying the existing `TextureParameter` object that is part of the `ColorLookup` component. Which will be automatically updated by Unity because this object exists in the scene.

Comment: I like this idea, however `SetDirty()` appears to be deprecated in favor of `EditorUtility.SetDirty()`, which is a class in the `UnityEditor` namespace and I need this to work in release version too. On top of that, the obsolete version, you've displayed using in your answer, doesn't seem to do work atm too. The `Volume` doesn't have such method it's only present in the profile or directly in the accessed module in this case `ColorLookup`, invoking it on either of those doesn't yield any change sadly.